# Python google wrapper for number of results

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, wrapper

I've seen some posts already to get the number of search results for a google search, but none is satisfying my needs so far. I want to search a string with blank spaces and get almost the same number of results as a manually executed search in google. My routine so far is

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


test='just a teststring for the search'
r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/search',
                     params={'q':test}
                    )
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html5lib")
test=soup.find('div',{'id':'resultStats'}).text
```

The routine gives 32400 search results, the manual search at the google page 85000, what am I doing wrong?! When I just search for one word, the deviation is much smaller.

Comment: Well the manual search is giving me `32600` results and the script is also giving the same number.

Comment: @moghya that's weird, maybe it depends also on the language of the computer filing the search? But in my native language (german), the result should be even lower

Comment: @moghya I'm in the university right now, I get 89000 results even here, how do you search manually?

Answer (score 0):

It will just always differ on each send request. Google search results are different on different computers, they want and expect search results to be different from person to person. It just depends on many factors.

In terms of send requests from bots (*scripts*), it is likely that the results will be the same, but not all the time.

For example:

```py
>>> soup.select_one('#result-stats nobr').previous_sibling
'About 4,100,000,000 results'
# in fact, there're was 4,000,000 results in my browser
```

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Number-of-Total-Search-Results-python-bs4#main.py):

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "step by step guide how to prank google",
  "gl": "us",
  "hl": "en"
}

response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

number_of_results = soup.select_one('#result-stats nobr').previous_sibling
print(number_of_results)

-----
# About 7,800,000 results
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The main difference is that you only need to iterate over structured JSON, without figuring out how to extract certain elements and coding everything from scratch. No need to maintain the parser.

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "step by step guide how to prank google",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

result = results["search_information"]['total_results']
print(result)

-----
# 7800000
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.