# Webscraping Google & Printing Search Result #

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from urllib2 import urlopen as open
from urllib2 import Request as request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import lxml

agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0' 
headers = {
    'User-Agent': agent 
}
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=gemini+horoscope'
r = request(url, headers=headers)
p = open(r) 
sauce = soup(p,'lxml')
res = sauce.find('div',{'id':'resultStats'})
print res.read()
```

--I feel like I'm doing way more than I need to, any help would be appreciated! This program is supposed to be simple and print only the search results number, but for some reason it is not working >_<

Answer (score 0):

You're super close. Instead of

```
print res.read()
```

try

```
print res.text
```

It should give you:

```
In [2]: print res.text
About 36,100,000 results (0.30 seconds)
```

If you just want the number, try

```
print res.text.split(' ')[1]
```

Comment: I tried that first, but each time I try to run it i receive a type error that says: 'unicode' object is not callable. Is there a library that I have to import first to be able to use the type function? P.S. I am running Python 2, could that be a reason why the text function does not work?

Comment: @Ty'TeonnaFranklin what you probably tried was `print res.text()`, which would give you the error you just described. That's because `text` is an attribute of the response, not a method. Just call it without the parentheses and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

from urllib2 import urlopen as open

from urllib2 import Request as request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

import lxml

agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101

Firefox/59.0' 
headers = {

```
'User-Agent': agent
```

}
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=gemini+horoscope'

r = request(url, headers=headers)

p = open(r)

sauce = soup(p,'lxml')

res = sauce.find('div',{'id':'resultStats'})

**print res.text.split(' ')[1]**

Comment: I don't understand why you just took my answer and posted your own, this is clearly exactly what I suggested you do.

Comment: I'm new to StackOverflow, I thought since your comment is obviously above the answer it'd be common sense that you were the reason for the answer. Sorry, didn't think that deep into it

Comment: Here's a little cheat sheet for what to do when someone answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

To extract the number of search you can use [`.select_one`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) in addition with [`.previous_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) `bs4` methods.

I wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68857576/15164646) to why the number of results is different.

```py
# locates css selector and goes to a previous sibling that doesn't have "(1.07 seconds)" part
>>> number_of_results = soup.select_one('#result-stats nobr').previous_sibling
'About 7,800,000 results'
```

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Number-of-Total-Search-Results-python-bs4#main.py):

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "step by step guide how to prank google",
  "gl": "us",
  "hl": "en"
}

response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

number_of_results = soup.select_one('#result-stats nobr').previous_sibling
print(number_of_results)

-----
# About 7,800,000 results
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to figure out why or how to do stuff, you can use [Google Search Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "step by step guide how to prank google",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

result = results["search_information"]['total_results']
print(result)

-----
# 7800000
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.